# css element and setInterval error

Tags: javascript, css, undefined

I get this error:

> cannot read property of 'css' undefined

and don't know how to fix it!

Here is the code:

```
//constructor for Car objects
var Car = function(x, y){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
};

//adding the draw method to Car objects
Car.prototype.draw = function(){
    //obtaining the image that the car will have
    var carHtml = '<img src = "http://nostarch.com/images/car.png">';

    // attaching the chosen image file to the current object being drawn
    this.carElement = $(carHtml);  

    //giving the image of the Car object its (x, y) position on the plane using css
    this.carElement.css({
        position: "absolute",
        left: this.x,
        top: this.y
});

    //attaching the image associated with the Car object to the body of the html document (the web page)
    $("body").append(this.carElement);  
};

//adding the moveRight method to Car objects
Car.prototype.moveRight = function(){
    this.x = this.x + 50;

    this.carElement.css({

        left: this.x,
        top: this.y
    });
};

var tdi = new Car(100, 200);  //creating a new instance of the Car class

tdi.draw();     //invoking the draw method on an object so it appears on the screen

var move = tdi.moveRight;
var run = setInterval(move, 30);
```

Any help?  Severely lacking in understanding here...

Comment: THANK YOU!  I am used to the "this" behavior in Java, not so much Javascript...

Answer (score 3):

This issue is cause, `this` does not refer to instance of `Car` inside `setInterval` function.
To fix it you can use [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).

```
var run = setInterval(move.bind(tdi), 30);
```

or without additional reference

```
var run = setInterval(tdi.moveRight.bind(tdi), 30);
```

Also, due to behavior of `this` context in javascrip it is a good practice to cache `this` context inside constractor and methods defined using prototype. It can prevent from some issues.
For example:

```
Car.prototype.draw = function() {
  var self_ = this; 
  //obtaining the image that the car will have
  var carHtml = '<img src = "http://nostarch.com/images/car.png">';

  // attaching the chosen image file to the current object being drawn
  self_.carElement = $(carHtml);  

  //giving the image of the Car object its (x, y) position on the plane using css
  self_.carElement.css({
    position: "absolute",
    left: self_.x,
    top: self_.y
  });
```

> A function's this keyword behaves a little differently in JavaScript compared to other languages. It also has some differences between strict mode and non-strict mode.

More information to understand this context in javascript [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

Comment: `var run = setInterval(move.bind(tdi), 30);`

Comment: `this.carElement.css({ left: this.x, top: this.y });` Also suggest him to cache the `this` outside this `.css()` function call. since `this` will point `window` inside a plain object.

Comment: Thanks, @RajaprabhuAravindasamy I've noted it in update.

Answer (score 0):

Behavior of "this" keyword in JavaScript is different from Object Oriented languages.

You can get around it by using .bind() like a another answer suggested. But you will keep bumping into issues around this area unless you understand how "this" behaves.

In short:

- Typical OO: "this" refers to the instance of the object, **method** of which was called.
- Javascript: "this" refers to how the **function** was called.

This is a good article to read:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Understanding "this", "prototype" and "closure" are vital to writing good JavaScript code.